# NetworkXError: Input is not a known data type for conversion

Tags: python, neo4j, networkx, graph-databases, py2neo

I want to create a networkx graph using the Neo4j GraphDB in VM. I have tried a bunch of things online but I'm getting the same error, when I'm trying to use py2neo to do the same, the error pops up and also when straight loading via a neo4j BoltDriver.

The implementation:

```
from neo4j import GraphDatabase
import networkx as nx

driver = GraphDatabase.driver(credentials['url'], auth=(credentials['user'], credentials['passwd']))

G = nx.Graph(driver)
```

Anything I'm missing? I have gone through the documentation of the networkx but sadly nothing relevant to the issue I'm facing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you're expecting to happen here, but you're passing a connectivity object (Driver) into the constructor for the NetworkX Graph data type. The error is clearly appearing because NetworkX doesn't know what do to with that Driver object.

Instead, you'll need to *extract* some data from the database by running a Cypher query, and then pass that data into the Graph constructor, assuming you have also coerced it into a form that NetworkX can accept.